GStreamer pipe to dynamically control alsasink
I have a GStreamer pipeline that receives an udp/rtp stream and outputs it to four soundcard channels, e.g. alsasinks:
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc name=m_udpsrc multicast-group=239.255.255.245 auto-multicast=true port=5551 timeout=30000000000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)G722, payload=(int)9" ! rtpg722depay name=m_depay ! avdec_g722 name=m_dec  ! audioconvert ! tee name=m_t  m_t. ! queue name=m_queue_1 ! volume volume=0.66 name=m_volume_ch1 ! alsasink name=ch1 device=card1_out0 sync=false async=true  m_t. ! queue name=m_queue_2 ! volume volume=0.66 name=m_volume_ch2 ! alsasink name=ch2 device=card1_out1 sync=false async=true  m_t. ! queue name=m_queue_3 ! volume volume=0.66 name=m_volume_ch3 ! alsasink name=ch3 device=card2_out0 sync=false async=true  m_t. ! queue name=m_queue_4 ! volume volume=0.66 name=m_volume_ch4 ! alsasink name=ch4 device=card2_out1 sync=false async=true

Is there a plugin with which I can dynamically enable/disable or mute/unmute one of the four channels (alsasinks) individually?
Since i have four alssinks the possible amount of gstreamer pipeline combinations is 1..16. But its very inefficient and time consuming to always teardown and setup a new pipeline once i have to switch channels or to another combination of channels.

Sure there is.. start wiring a real application for this. This is out of the scope of the gst-launch-1.0 tool.

Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "start wiring a real application". Do you mean developing a custom gstreamer plugin to control this?

No, an application. gst-launch-1.0 is a general purpose application. It helps quikcly testing and prototyping. For your more advanced use cases you should write an application yourself creating gstreamer pipleines. This allows you to dynamically react on events. See https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/index.html?gi-language=c

For the actual question, check the volume plugin. It has a mute property.

volume plugin with mute property does the job. Important here is that in general the plugin property must be controllable, i.e. must have the GST_PARAM_CONTROLLABLE flag on property creation. I did a small python script and now i can dynamically mute/unmute channels while streaming:
#0:   ch1: True  ch2: False ch3: True  ch4: False
#1:   ch1: False ch2: True  ch3: False ch4: True
#2:   ch1: True  ch2: False ch3: True  ch4: False
#3:   ch1: False ch2: False ch3: False ch4: False
#4:   ch1: True  ch2: False ch3: True  ch4: False

Based on @florian-zwoch comments, using the volume plugin with the mute property does the job.

There is no plugin that I know of that would allow you to mute the pipeline with a gst-launch command.
There are some tools that allow you to prototype more without the need of a full gstreamer application. Gstreamer Daemon is useful when you need to dynamically update properties in a test pipeline. For your case you could use that tool to update the volume of the different pipelines and mute them.

Seems an interesting approach. Could you tell a little bit more about this tool?

The Gstreamer Daemon runs as a separate process which manages the state of pipelines and properties of each element. A inter process communication channel is made available so that the user can interact with the pipeline, signals, element properties.

This allows to interact with pipelines in the usual ways (start/stop/delete) but you can also do things like send events (EOS/Seek/Flush). Lastly, it allows to check signals and modify properties.
